# capistrano dev deploy fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm

A bit new to the capistrano deploys so I'm struggling with getting this to work correctly.  I found another entry saying this is a symlink issue but I don't think it is since "cap dev deploy" creates the current symlink correctly. I have a stage and a dev environment on this server (/apps/myhost/dev and /apps/myhost/stage) and I'm looking to push my most recent git changes from git to the dev environment.  I SSH in as the application user and do:

```
cap dev deploy
```

I receive the following error:

```
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm-shell 'ree@myhost' -c 'bundle install --gemfile /apps/myhost/dev/releases/20110526014237/Gemfile --path /apps/myhost/dev/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on dev.myhost.com
```

Which is preceded by a lot of:

```
rm: cannot remove directory `/apps/myhost/dev/releases/20110526014237/test/functional': No such file or directory
```

I assume the rm error is because the directory and files have already been cleaned up but I'm uncertain why the rvm_path rvm-shell fails?

Comment: Ok. I updated all the gems and cap is now doing this: `code`bash: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/bin/cap: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
`code`

Comment: Fixed the bad interpreter error and now I'm back where I started: `code` failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked my /apps/myapp/dev/config/deploy/ directory and found these files:

```
dev.rb
stage.rb
prod.rb
```

Had role and server variables set so it was trying to deploy twice causing the lock. Removed the server line and was able to deploy.

Regarding the trust; added this line to config/deploy.rb:

```
task :trust_rvmrc do
    run "rvm rvmrc trust #{latest_release}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you run the failing command yourself by SSHing in? It looks like it's failing on installing the bundle. Do you have Bundler installed? I've never used Cap to deploy two environments under /apps/. Can you get it to work with just one environment? Lastly, I'd try fixing those rm errors before trying to tackle anything after them. One thing at a time.

Comment: Ian, thanks for the feed back. I actually had been SSHíng in. I fixed it today. Under the config/deploy my stage, dev, and prod .rb files all set the server and role variables.  You can only specify one or the other. I removed the server variable from each (since it was trying to deploy to the URL as well as the IP - specified under role) and it worked.  Now all that's left is to make it rvm rmrc trust on each deploy!